# How to force supervisord to stop a process in BACKOFF status

Tags: supervisord

When you start a process using supervisord it is in "STARTING" status then if it gets trouble it gets in "BACKOFF" status if there is an autorestart set to true.

I don't want to wait for "startretries" to be attempted, I want to stop the restarting process manually using supervisorctl. The only way I found to do so is to stop the entire supervisord service and start it again (every process go in "STOPPED" status if there is no autostart).

Is there a better way to do so (force "STOPPED" status from "BACKOFF" status) as I have other processes managed in supervisord that I don't want to stop?

If I try to stop it with

```
supervisorctl stop process
```

I get

```
FAILED: attempted to kill process with sig SIGTERM but it wasn't running
```

If I try to start it with

```
supervisorctl start process
```

I get

```
process: ERROR (already started)
```

Of course I could disable the autorestart, but it can be useful, a workaround is to limit the startretries, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

Hey this maybe help for you:

> When an autorestarting process is in the BACKOFF state, it will be
>   automatically restarted by supervisord. It will switch between
>   **STARTING** and **BACKOFF** states until it becomes evident that it cannot be started because the number of **startretries** has exceeded
>   the maximum, at which point it will transition to the FATAL state.
>   Each start retry will take progressively more time.

so you don't need to stop the BACKOFF process manually. if you do not want to wait too long time, it is better to set a little number to startretries.

see more info here: http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html

GOOD LCUKY

Comment: this really doesnt address the question - you simply told him he doesn't need to do what he asked.   " you don't need to stop the BACKOFF process manually".   

he's asking how he can switch from BACKOFF to STOPPED state, so he can be confidence the process doesn't start back up.

Answer (score -6):

Use the following command to force supervisor to stop a process in the BACKOFF state.

```
supervisorctl stop <gname>:*
```